# Sorting keys of dictionary according to more than one criteria - Python 3.0

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key, alphabetical

I'm trying to get a sorted dictionary. The dictionary should be sorted according to the following two criteria:

1. According to the values (integers)
2. If two keys (str) have the same value, sort alphabetically

So far, I have written the following line in my code:

```
sorted_word_values_dict = dict(sorted(word_values_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

This code sorts correctly according to the first criteria, but if two keys (str) have the same value (e.g. both have a value of 2), they need to be sorted alphabetically. How can I include this extra criterium in my code?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `sorted(word_values_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))` > first sort using `x[1] - values in dict`, if they are same then sort using `x[0] - dict key name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambda as a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) in `sorted` call

Following should get you the new `dict` in sorted order -

```
sorted_word_values_dict = dict(sorted(word_values_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])))
```

The `key` argument in sorted function can take a function which returns multiple values, in case there is a tie between the first value, the comparison would move to next value in the key.

In this example, `x[1]`(dict value) would be compared first, if it is identical, we would compare the `x[0]`(dict key).

Answer (score 2):

Given this dictionary:

```
d = {'c': 1251, 'b': 2372, 'f': 5172, 'a': 2372}
```

If you want to sort the values in ascending order and keys lexicographically:

```
out = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0])))
```

Output:

```
{'c': 1251, 'a': 2372, 'b': 2372, 'f': 5172}
```

If however, you want to sort values in descending order (and keys lexicographically):

```
out = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0])))
```

Output:

```
{'f': 5172, 'a': 2372, 'b': 2372, 'c': 1251}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on how to sort in descending order, I sure will need this in another exercise! I appreciate your help.